# Does $\int_1^2\frac{\sin{x}}{\log{x}} \, dx$ converge?

Tags: improper-integrals

I tried to use the absolute convergence test.
$$\int_1^2\left|\frac{\sin{x}}{\log{x}}\right| \, dx<\int_1^2\left|\frac{1}{\log{x}}\right| \, dx$$
but I'm not sure whether $\frac{1}{\log{x}}$ converges or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $\log x$ at $x = 1$?

Comment: 0 so it must diverge but then the comparison test doesn't work.. Any other way?

Comment: Just because $\log(1) = 0$ doesn't mean $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\log}$ doesn't converge. It doesn't converge because at 1 $\log$ goes to 0 as $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: What Solomonoff said, @Gregory.  The denominator of an integrand being $0$ at an endpoint of integration isn't a sufficient condition for the integral diverging.  For example, $\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt x} \, dx = 2$.

Comment: Very true guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: for $x > 1$, $\log{x} < x-1$, so $\frac{1}{\log{x}} > \frac{1}{x-1}$. $\sin{1}$ is not zero, and $1<\pi/2$, so sine is increasing for $x$ near $1$. Therefore on the interval $(1,\epsilon)$,
$$ \frac{\sin{x}}{\log{x}} > \frac{\sin{1}}{x-1}, $$
and the right-hand side does not have a convergent integral. Hence by comparison, neither does the left-hand side.